# Support different screen sizes (Mobile and IPad/Android tablets) for React Native Application

Tags: javascript, react-native, responsive-design

I want to create a responsive layout for my **react-native** application as follows. I already created a mobile device (iPhone and android phone) layouts. But project owner requesting to create some responsive layouts for **iPad and other android tablets according to their screen sizes**. I have an idea of how to create those responsive layouts using android and swift native programming languages, but I do not have any idea, how to create these IPad flexible layouts using the same react-native component.

I'm doing my research but still, I did not found an answer to this. I like to know your ideas about this and it will help me to find a better solution. Really appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.

[image: mobile view]

[image: IPad View]

Comment: Check screen width and change the UI using conditiional rendering

Answer (score 0):

If you want to responsive your app for all screen sizes then use window prop to set width, height, font size, border radius etc. In following example you can get an idea about that

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const window = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    backIconContainer: {
        marginTop: (window.width) * 0.02,
        marginLeft: (window.width) * 0.02,
        fontSize: (window.width) * 0.055,
        width:(window.width) * 0.8,

    },
  
});

export default styles;
```